# How to create Java Azure Function that has Service Bus Output without defining specific subscription?

Tags: azure-functions

I have Java HTTP Triggered Function, which have Service Bus Topic as output.
However it does send message to specific Subscription defined in Output Binding.
I wish the message can be subscribed by several subscribers.

So my question is how to configure code or service base?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=java

```
FunctionName("sbtopicsend")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = 
AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @ServiceBusTopicOutput(name = "message", topicName = "mytopicname", subscriptionName = 
"mysubscription", connection = "ServiceBusConnection") OutputBinding<String> message,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        String name = request.getBody().orElse("Azure Functions");

        message.setValue(name);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send messages to a subscription, only a queue or a topic. I believe the `subscriptionName` property is not really required here.

Your code should be sending messages to the topic itself and any subscription with the appropriate filters (or none) should be receiving the messages.